# MySQL: `SHOW INDEX` shows differently than `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand why an index isn't being created the way I expected it. I was in the process of investigating what happened when I created a HASH index on top of an existing foreign key.

```
create table users (id int, primary key(id));
create table temp (id int not null, primary key(id), user_id int(11) default null);
```

Right now there is no foreign key yet. `show create table temp;` outputs what you'd expect:

```
| temp  | CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

And `show index from temp`:

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| temp  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Everything is good. Now lets add a FK:

```
alter table temp add foreign key key_name (user_id) references users (id);
```

This shows us `show create table temp;`:

```
| temp  | CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `key_name` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

and `show index from temp;`

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| temp  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| temp  |          1 | key_name |            1 | user_id     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

So far so good: we have added a foreign key constraint and MySQL automatically added a BTREE index which it uses to enforce the constraint.

Now I would like that index to be a HASH so I'm adding it:

```
create index index_name using hash on temp (user_id);
```

Here's where it becomes strange. You can see the `KEY (...) USING HASH` entry when you do `show create table temp` as expected:

```
| temp  | CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_name` (`user_id`) USING HASH,
  CONSTRAINT `temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

However when you do `show index from temp;`

```
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| temp  |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| temp  |          1 | index_name |            1 | user_id     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Nothing changed! And the index is still a BTREE!.

What is going on here?

EDIT: someone called to my attention that maybe `create index ...` isn't the same as `alter table add index ...` somehow. Well I tried it, and they're certainly doing the same thing. `alter table temp add index (user_id) using hash` leads to

```
| temp  | CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_name` (`user_id`) USING HASH,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING HASH,
  CONSTRAINT `temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |



+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| temp  |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| temp  |          1 | index_name |            1 | user_id     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| temp  |          1 | user_id    |            1 | user_id     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Issue is quite trivial - InnoDB and MyISAM engines do not permit `hash` index type, so they silently fall back to the one they use, which is `btree`. Is there a reason why you're enforcing the hash index type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InnoDB storage engine only supports `BTREE` indexes, not `HASH` indexes.

When you tried to create a `HASH` index, it silently converted the index to `BTREE`.